# How to send multiple values in many2many field in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to generate purchase order from manufacturing order.I have created many2many field for getting multiple products.I want to send multiple product ids to my custom function.I am able to send 1 value but sending more than one gives error as `Expected singleton: product.template(4, 3)`.

```
from openerp import models,fields,api
class generate_purchase_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'mrp_to_purchase_order'
    product_id = fields.Many2many('product.template',string='Products',required=True)

    @api.multi    
    def generate_purchase_order2(self):
        for wizard in self:
            mrp_obj = self.env['mrp.production']
            mrp_obj.generate_purchase_order(wizard.product_id.id) #function call
        return { 'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

mrp_custom.py,

```
from openerp import models,api
class mrp_production(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    @api.multi
    def generate_purchase_order(self,product_id):
        purchase_line_obj = self.env['purchase.order.line']

        context = self._context
        for order in self.browse(context['active_ids']):     
            for line in order.bom_id.bom_line_ids:    
                if line.product_id.id != product_id:#problem line
                    continue
                #rest of code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
singleton: product.template(4, 3)
```

This error means that code is expecting **single record** not recordset, so you must change code to allow recordset using or make ensureone with try-catch and avoid errors. Thats general information.

Now if you want to get multiple records from many2many its not problem at all, you must pass this many2many object only and then work with it.
After getting many2many object to work with every record from this recordset you must use `for record in recordset:`

Also `wizard.product_id.id` **this is error!!!** product_id is many2many so you must pass product_id or if you want to browse by yourself you must pass **product_id.ids**

Comment: I think it should store product_id as list so that I can retreive it through for loop in the called function

Comment: You can use recordset in loop and list too but recordset is the way more easy, if you want just list of ids then use product_id.ids just like one2many it will give you all the ids related to it

Comment: I tried like this:  for record in product_ids:
                print record.product_id.id

Comment: I got 'int' object has no attribute product_id

Comment: when using ids you are getting list of ids (in int) so you are getting correct error, in this case you must make self.env['model'].browse(id) to get record.
OR as i said you can pass recordset and browse won't be necessary

Comment: when using recordset you have for example: crm.lead(1, 3, 9) and when using ids you have [1, 3, 9]

Comment: can it hold more than 10 id?

Comment: I think yes, I didn't tested with so much records but nothing is against it, why not. There may be thousands of records, depending on project sizes